# SugarCRM Rest API: Required fields for a Meeting entry?

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm trying to create a Meeting entry via the API, but I can't seem to find it in my calendar even though it saved successfully (I got the ID back) and I can see it in the Meetings list.

What fields do I need to populate for it to show in my Sugar calendar? Here are the fields I'm populating:

```
{
 'assigned_user_id': '1', # My user's ID
 'date_end': '2013-04-16 01:30:00',
 'date_start': '2013-04-16 01:23:45',
 'description': 'hello world',
 'location': 'JCenter',
 'name': 'Test',
 'team_id': '1',
 'type': 'Sugar' # This doesn't seem to be required
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set "user_id" and take a look into mettings_users table where you will find it.

Comment: Did my answer help you or is the task resolved? Please give feedback on my answer.